# Приведение типов у ссылок и указателей

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, типы

```
int y=0;
double z=1.9;
y=z;

int* py;
double* pz;
//py=pz; error
//int& rp=z; error
```

Вопрос: почему можно присвоить переменной одного типа другую, а с указателями и ссылками так нельзя?

Comment: `y=z;` - это не приведение типов. Создаётся временный объект другого типа и идёт присваивание. `y = ( int ) ( z ) ;` Новый указатель не может быть создан из указателя другого типа. А число с плавающей запятой может, правда с другим значением. Как компилятор и предупредит. Есть случаи возможности присвоения указателей, если они родственные классы например, тогда можно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что при присвоении переменных происходит копирование значения **с преобразованием к нужному типу** (Например, 1.9 преобразуется в 1), в то время как при работе с указателями вы просто копируете адрес, и получается, что то, что лежит, например, по адресу в памяти `double*`, представляет собой именно `double`, а вы пытаетесь сказать "там не `double`, там `int`". А представления в памяти у них совершенно разные. Биты на одних и тех же местах имеют разный смысл. А еще и размеры могут не совпадать, и при присвоении (записи значения по адресу) вы запросто можете затирать чужую память.

Словом, это слишком опасная операция, чтобы разрешить ее просто так, неявно. А явно — вы можете сказать компилятору "я лучше знаю, что делаю!", типа

```
int * py = (int*)pz;
```

Только вот что из этого получится? См. пример такого преобразования https://ideone.com/mClrR1

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим не встроенные типа, а классы для понятности. Классы

```cpp
class A{};
class B{};
```

несовместимы. И присвоение друг другу не предусмотрено как по значению так и по указателю так и по ссылке.
А родственные классы уже могут взаимодействовать

```cpp
class A{};
class B:public A{};
B b ;
B * bp = & b ;
B & bl = b ;
A a = b ; 
A & al = bl ;
A * ap = bp ;
```

Так как в памяти объект типа B содержит часть объекта типа A. И компилятор может рассматривать только родственную часть.

Типы `int` и `double` не родственные и их указатели вы не сможете присваивать друг к другу. А значение можете, так как существует приведение одного типа к другому. В классах это выглядело бы так :

```cpp
class A{};
class B{
public:
  B(A const&){}
};
```

Comment: Тогда, получается, можно рассматривать типа `short int` и `long int` как родственные?... Как-то непонятен этот момент. Есть ли родственные, кроме как среди наследуемых классов?

Comment: Родственный я говору если один тип является частью другого. В Си `struct B{inti0;}; struct A { struct B base; int i1;}; struct A a ; struct B * b=&a.base;`  можно назвать как родственные, а если **бы** тип `long int` был реализован как массив шортов, то тоже. `typedef short  int long_int [ 4 ] ; long_int a[ 4 ] ; short b=a[0];` @Harry